# I use B to select 2 vertices but on 2 different sides, and i right click to drag and it only moves one

Tags: vertices

help would be great I can't think of a reason why this is happening. I have a square with a subdivision surface modifier and i use B to select two vertices on 2 different sides of the shape and my right click only drags one. any heLP?

Comment: When you start dragging, Blender first selects the vertex which is closest to the pointer afaik. The it moves just that vertex. Use the g key instead to move both selected objects at the same time. g activates translation.

Comment: did my answer solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use <kbd>C</kbd> in edit mode to select vertices in a circular way or use <kbd>B</kbd> to select in a box way. Once you select the vertices you want then you can hit <kbd>G</kbd> to grab/translate the vertices you want as shown below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: C selects with Circular selector, B selects with Box (square) selector. But the point of the OP was about right click dragging behaviour, not selecting...